# showing drawable and bitmap in view pager memory leaks

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, drawable

I am dealing with drawables and bitmap , an app to show the cards.I have to show them in a cyclic view pager, and done all these thing successfully , but when I spend a lot of time (more than 1 min) to swipe between view pager, the app is not more responding and also the heap also exceeds

```
Grow heap (frag case) to 151.649MB for 4004016-byte allocation
```

I have done following things:
->show drawable in view pager (all the images are stored in drawable-nodpi folder)
->change drawable to bitmap then again show in another view pager
->also apply the on touch listener with gesture detector and scale detector on the imageview

I have done following code:

```
 PagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {


            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return total_length;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                if (str.equals("free")) {

                    int str = Cons.drawableAry_all[position];
                     return OfferSingleFragment.newInstance(str,""+position);
                }
                else if(str.equals("heart"))
                {
                    int str = Cons.drawableAry_heart_felt[position];
                     return OfferSingleFragment.newInstance(str,""+position);
                }
                else
                {
                    int str = Cons.drawableAry_funny[position];
                     return OfferSingleFragment.newInstance(str,""+position);
                }
            }
        };

        // wrap pager to provide infinite paging with wrap-around
        PagerAdapter wrappedAdapter = new InfinitePagerAdapter(adapter);

        pager.setAdapter(wrappedAdapter);
```

and in fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_layout,container,false);
    View txt = v.findViewById(R.id.img_template);
    View img_changephoto =v.findViewById(R.id.img_changephoto);
    layout = (FrameLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.linear);

    drawable = getArguments().getInt("drawable") ;
      String t = getArguments().getString("pos") ;
         Log.d("OnCreateView",">>"+t);


        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
         int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
         int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, width);
    ((ImageView)txt).setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    if (PreferenceActivity.getCardStatus(getActivity()).equals("removed")) {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
             options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
             Bitmap preview_bitmap = Cons.drawableToBitmap(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(drawable));
              Bitmap b =  Bitmap.createBitmap(preview_bitmap,
                     preview_bitmap.getWidth()-170,40,150, 150);

 Bitmap b1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b,preview_bitmap.getWidth()-130, 40, false);
            ((ImageView)txt).setImageBitmap(mergeBitmap(preview_bitmap, b1));

        }
        else
        {
            ((ImageView)txt).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(drawable));

        }
```

}

Can somebody help me to show the drawable/bitmap efficiently without ANRs .

Answer (score 0):

Always, always, remember to `recycle()` all the bitmaps that are not needed anymore. I see you are creating three bitmaps: `preview_bitmap`, `b` and `b1`. After calling mergeBitmap recycle the bitmaps used. Furthermore, you have to recycle the result of mergeBitmap somewhere else, after you assign another bitmap to `txt`.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions:

- Do not perform bitmap creation/modification on main(ui) thread. Try
  to provide a mechanism to perform operations in background thread.
- Be sure that bitmap.recycle method is called for every bitmap you
  have created, after view containing bitmap is destroyed.
- Try to provide a cache to reuse processed bitmaps.
- Also a good alternative might be storing source images in assets directory and using glide to load them. Glide will be performing caching and reusing operations for you.
- You may use FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter in order to preserve memory

Answer (score 0):

If there is an option to not use a `ViewPager` and use some other views like a `RecyclerView`, go for it. It does view recycling. In a project, I was using `HorizontalScrollView` to display images horizontally and the app used to crash after some time, as the memory footprint increased. When I replaced the `HorizontalScrollView` with `RecyclerView`, the app didn't crash even once. Also try [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) library for displaying images. It uses `ashmen` cache and is very effective in removing Out of Memory errors compared with other image loading libraries like Picasso or UIL. Finally, adding this line in you `Application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` file also helps to some extent:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: hello thanks for your response ,can it is possible to show the drawables using Fresco , and also , showing the images from asset intead of drawabale ,will be good , I need to show around 42 images at a time in view pager

Comment: @userAndroid Yes it is possible. See [this](http://frescolib.org/docs/supported-uris.html) for a list of supported URIs by fresco. Also, please upvote the answer or mark it correct if it helped you.

Comment: I will upvote if it will be helpful , let me try first